# Trigger combinelatest from another component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have component A and B. In component A's `ngOnInit`, I load the initial data through `combineLatest`.

```js
this.filteredProduct$ = combineLatest([
  this.productDataList$,
  this.productFilterApplied$,
  this.collectionFilterApplied$,
  this.statusFilterApplied$,
  this.unitPriceFilterApplied$,
  this.markUpFilterApplied$
]).pipe(...).subscribe((data) => {this.list = data;}); // list will be rendered in UI.
```

In component B, I have some button actions, click the button will update list in component A.

In another word, I have to call `combineLatest` in component A again. I am not sure how can I trigger it since they are in different components?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, depending on your component structure:

- For example if B is a child component of A, B can output an event using [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). In the event handler in A you can call `next` on a [BevaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) and that `BehaviorSubject` is part of list you give to `combineLatest`. You need `BehaviorSubject`as it initially emits a value, otherwise `combineLatest`would not fire.
- If A and B have no relationship you can make the `BehaviorSubect` public in A and call `next`from B.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to move the Subjects and Observables into a service. Component B can `.next()` those Subjects in the button click events, then the service can update the Observables which can then be consumed in Component A. This would be preferable to having the two components being coupled by referencing one anothers' members.